# Passage continuing north/to the north

Tags: sentence-structure

There is a passage continuing north/to the north.

Which one is correct? Is it better without using "to the"?

Answer (score 2):

I would use either "to the north" or "north**ward**".

As for which is better, there's really no preference. It's a coin toss.